# How identify a user session ? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i have this routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'login#new'
  get '/home/inicio', to: 'home#index'

  scope '/login' do
    get '/acesso', to:'login#new'
    post '/acessorecebendo', to:'login#create', as:'user'
    get '/sair', to:'login#destroy'
  end

  resources :login
  resources :home
  resources :produtos
  resources :fornecedors
end
```

the Login controller:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery

  def new
    if session[:user]
      @user = User.find(session[:user])
    end
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to "/login/acesso", notice: "Você foi deslogado"
  end

  def create
    user = User.validate(login_params[:email], login_params[:senha])

    if user
      session[:user] = user.id
      redirect_to "/home/inicio", notice: "login feito com sucesso"
    else
      redirect_to "/login/acesso", notice: "Dados incorretos"
    end
  end

  private
  def login_params
    params.require(:login).permit(:email, :senha)
  end
end
```

The home controller:

```
    class HomeController < ApplicationController   protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def new
    @user = User.find_by(id: session[:user])   end

  def index
    @produtos = Produto.all
    render 'inicio'   end

  def show
    if session[:user]
      @user = User.find(session[:user])
    end   end end
```

I'm getting an error on the Home view (new.html.erb):

```
<header>
  <h2><a href="#">Bem-vindo <%= @user.nome %></a></h2>
  <nav>
```

> undefined method `nome' for nil:NilClass

Why i have some problems with the session? I can do the login and i wanna see the user informations of this session on the redirected page, like if i can pass the @user variable assigned on the login action to the home controller to use it.

Comment: Hello again. What is this??? `@user = @user = User.find(session[:user])`. Also, you need a `new` action to set the user.

Comment: oh, this is a mistake when i texting this post...
my teacher is horrible :\\

but what u mean with a new action? i've been updated the post.

Comment: Your authentication method is deeply flawed - you're just storing the user's id in the session cookie? You should be using a token that gets reset every time the user logs in or logs out. With this method, it's really trivial for someone to impersonate other users, and a session token could be reused for a lot time...

That said. Can we see the code for `User::validate`?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `@user` is being set only in index and show, but you are trying to reference it from the new action.

Consider moving this logic to a [`before_action`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action if: ->{ session[:user] } do
    @user = User.find_by(id: session[:user])
  end
end
```

If this controller needs to assume that `@user` is present, you should also have a `before_action` that handles the case of a missing user account. I usually put this behavior into a `AuthenticatedController` class and inherit from it where needed.

`User.find` is not optimal here, because it will throw an exception if no record is found.

Comment: Why you are saying "trying to reference it from the new action" ? the routes get '/home/inicio', to: 'home#index' so in the index action i rendered my view which i'm trying to use @user variable value.

Comment: @MikhaelAraujo `/home/inicio` is linked to `home#index` and so uses `index.html.erb` by default. Your example shows `new.html.erb` as the culprit, and your controller code is not rendering it explicitly, so I have to assume that it is being rendered by the `HomesController#new` action. That route was wired up by `resources :home`.